# fs.createReadStream is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, fs

Here is my snippet:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import FormData from 'form-data';
var fs = require('fs');

submitCareerForm(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        let formData = new FormData();    //formdata object

        formData.append('first_name',this.state.fname);
        formData.append('last_name',this.state.lname);
        formData.append('cv', fs.createReadStream(this.state.cv));
        formData.append('email', this.state.email);
        formData.append('phone',this.state.phone);
        formData.append('details',this.state.details);
        formData.append('preferred_contact',this.state.preferredContact);

        console.log('resume ****** ',this.state.cv)

        let config = {
            method: 'post',
            url: 'https://sbtsbackend.azurewebsites.net/users/carrers',
            data : formData
        };

        axios(config)
        .then(resData => {
            console.log('result data ******** ',resData)
            if(resData.data.statusCode == 200){
                alert(resData.data.message);
            }
            this.setState({
                fname: '',
                lname: '',
                cv: '',
                address: '',
                city: '',
                state: '',
                postalcode: '',
                country: '',
                phone: '',
                email: '',
                details: '',
            });
        })
        .catch((error)=>{
            console.log('error ******* ',error)
        })

    }
```

I want to upload document type doc, docx or pdf. On postman the api is working fine. How can I implement here?

This is the error I am getting:

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to use `fs` in the frontend?

Comment: If you're trying to bundle some code to run in the front-end, you can't use the `fs` module in the web browser.  The capabilities the `fs` module uses don't exist in the browser.

Comment: `fs` is meant to be for backend not frontend.

Comment: yes I tried on frontend. what is the other way to upload the document using axios or fetch with formdata on frontend?

Comment: Hello@AnkushRishi, Can you solve it. Please help me. I am still have this problem. Can't find any solutions.

Answer (score 2):

The `fs` module for Node.js is only available for server side applications. When you use it in a web browser for client side applications, it will throw an error.

Comment: What could be the other possible way to send data from frontend to upload document. I tried to send the path only but did not work. like this: formData.append('cv', this.state.cv);

Comment: I recommend looking at the HTML file input element. Here's a tutorial that I think would be very useful for you: https://programmingwithmosh.com/javascript/react-file-upload-proper-server-side-nodejs-easy/